# ifconfig shows an IP out of the lan range

Tags: linux, networking

I have set router IP to 192.168.112.20 and starting IP address to 192.168.112.25. But when I run `ifconfig` command it shows the following IPs:

`inet addr: 192.168.174.12 Bcast 192.168.174.255 Mask:255.255.255.0`

in Network manager in IPv4 Settings, Method is set to *Automatic (DHCP)*

Why they're not in defined range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because someone else has another DHCP server on the network that responded first.

Comment: Can you explain more? I have only a windows computer(connected with cable) and a Linux system in my network

Comment: There isn't anything to explain. Somehow there is a second DHCP server on your network.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm connected to my own access point.Is there anything else to check?

Comment: Check what machine is at the default gateway in your routing.